# Text Input Disappearing on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form that pops out when you hover over the 'Login' link.  Clicking off the form causes the login form to hide.  My problem is that when I submit the form (via the submit button or pressing enter) the username disappears from the form.  This only happens in IE9 (not sure about previous versions of IE).  It works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.  I also confirmed that all text fields on the form lost their contents while password fields retain their value on submit.

I am stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my form code:

```
<fieldset id='signin_menu'>
<form name='headlogin' method='post' id='signin' action='/login'>
<label for='username'>Username</label>
<input type='text' name='username' size='13' maxlength='20'>
</p>
<p>
<label for='password'>Password</label>
<input type='password' name='password' size='13' maxlength='20'>
</p>
<p class='remember'>
<input type='submit' id='signin_submit' value='Sign in'>
<input type='checkbox' id='remember' name='keeplogin'>
<label for='remember'>Remember me</label>
</p>
<p class='forgot'> <a href='/forgot-password' id='resend_password_link'>Forgot your password?</a> </p>
<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='1' />
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".signin").mouseover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("fieldset#signin_menu").show();
        $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
    });

    $("fieldset#signin_menu").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).parent("a.signin").length==0) {
            $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
            $("fieldset#signin_menu").hide();
        }
    });

});
```